# auto groups in CentOS 7 in Active Directory domain?

Tags: centos, active-directory, sssd

I am having an issue that might be mostly cosmetic but I've gotta keep the user complaints down. :)

I have a set of servers running CentOS 7.4 and have the requirement to join the servers to an Active Directory domain. The users are defined in the domain with POSIX attributes but there are not groups defined for each user. I joined the domain with

```
realm join --user=me --membership-software=adcli --computer-name=myhostname EXAMPLE.GOV
```

My `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` contains this

```
[sssd]
domains = example.gov
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
default_domain_suffix = EXAMPLE.GOV

[domain/example.gov]
ad_domain = example.gov
krb5_realm = EXAMPLE.GOV
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_sasl_authid = myhostname$
ldap_id_mapping = False
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
ldap_user_home_directory = unixHomeDirectory
access_provider = ad
full_name_format = %1$s
override_shell = /bin/bash
```

So far so good but I do have a problem with getting a group name for myself.

```
$ id me
uid=123456(me) gid=123456 groups=123456
$ getent passwd me
me:*:123456:123456:Doug:/home/me:/bin/bash
$ getent group me
$
```

What I want is for `getent group me` to return `123456`. It looks like the `sssd` configuration options `auto_private_groups` or magicPrivateGroups (`magic_private_groups`?) is what I'm looking for but neither option is supported under CentOS 7.

Turning on `ldap_id_mapping` is not a option as these ids are not consistent across all of our platforms. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you got an entry in /etc/nsswitch.conf for groups pointing to the AD?

Comment: @RamanSailopal Yes. /etc/nsswitch is set to 'files sss' for passwd, shadow, and group.

Comment: Since you've got `ldap_id_mapping = false` and presumably no POSIX `gidNumber` identifiers in AD, what is to determine that your GID should be 123456?

Comment: @roaima We do have POSIX identifiers in AD for the user OU which does have gidNumber=123456, otherwise the passwd entry would not come up correctly. The problem is that there is no entry for me in the group OU.

Comment: Yes. So what are you expecting to be able to define the mapping of group id 123456 to some group name?

Comment: @roaima This is doable with "id_provider = ldap" and is supposedly doable using the auto_private_groups configuration keyword, which isn't supported yet under CentOS 7. I'm looking for a way to get it working under 'id_provider = ad' so I don't have to mess with setting up a ldap bind password that expires every 90 days in my organization.

Comment: Oh I see. I wasn't familiar with that new feature. How many users does this affect on any one machine? Perhaps you could use `pam_exec` to add an entry in the local `/etc/groups` as a user logs in? (If this is viable I can give you a fuller answer.)

Comment: @roaima Roughly 500 users on each of 600 machines. I had not thought of pam_exec but I ruled out using puppet because of the number of entries that needed to be added to /etc/group. Thanks for the tip.