# Authentication mechanism to connect to Windows AD in Linux?

Tags: centos, authentication, ldap, active-directory

My company has asked me to look into connecting our CentOS 7 instance's to our Active Directory to make it easier for user management.

I have so far looked at:

- Kerberos, doing it via command line - [How To Join CentOS Linux To An Active Directory Domain](https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-join-centos-linux-to-an-active-directory-domain/)
- OpenLDAP - [24.7. Configuring a System to Authenticate Using OpenLDAP](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-ldap-pam.html)

Is there any other tool or resource I should look into to do my due diligence?

Comment: One thing to look out for is by following the instructions in your first link, all users are in the same default group. I'm working through this now but don't have a great answer. [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426129/auto-groups-in-centos-7-in-ad-domain)

Comment: @DougO'Neal I personally did not want all users to be able to log into the sever so in the sshd_config, i added `AllowGroups sudoers node_access` as is it was missing from the config.  i then created a sudoers and node_access file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` and set up the group permissions in the respective files.  To make this work on my CentOS machine, i had to edit `/etc/security/access.conf` and add the groups `sudoers node_access` to the section under `# Same, but make sure that really the group wheel and not the user
# wheel is used (use nodefgroup argument, too):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sssd` and `realmd` was by far the easiest way to get this done.  The below steps are what I did to get my CentOS machine on the domain and able to restrict access to only the specific users in the security groups in Active Directory (AD).

**NOTE:** All steps from the below two links:

- https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-join-centos-linux-to-an-active-directory-domain/
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/545058/ssh-allow-windows-ad-groupswith-special-charactors

#### Install the packages

```
$ sudo yum install -y sssd realmd oddjob oddjob-mkhomedir adcli \
   samba-common samba-common-tools krb5-workstation openldap-clients \
   policycoreutils-python
```

Edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` file & insert the following two lines:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
search <domain>
nameserver <ip>
```

#### Joining to AD DOM

Join the Linux machine to the domain to be seen in Active Directory & to view that you are now on the domain:

```
$ sudo realm join --user=<user with permissions to add users to the domain> <domain>
$ sudo realm list
```

Edit `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`:

*From*

```
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
```

*To*

```
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
```

Then restart the `sssd` service:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart sssd
```

#### Setup sudo

Create the groups that will be used in AD in `/etc/sudoers.d/<group Name>` & edit the file and add the user access:

```
$ sudo touch /etc/sudoers.d/sudoers
$ sudo vi !$
```

Insert into `sudoers` file the permissions you want for this group:

```
%sudoers    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

**NOTE:** Have a system admin create the same groups in AD.

Edit which groups or users can access the system via SSH. Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add the groups to the `AllowGroups` section.  You may need to add `AllowGroups` to config file, I had to:

```
AllowGroups sudoers node_access
```

I have two groups, `sudoers` and `node_access`. Edit `/etc/security/access.conf` and add the groups into this file to only allow ssh access for users in the `sudoers` and `node_access` group.

Add the groups in ()'s to the below section of the `access.conf` file:

```
# Same, but make sure that really the group wheel and not the user
# wheel is used (use nodefgroup argument, too):
#
-:ALL EXCEPT (wheel) shutdown sync:LOCAL (sudoers) (node_access)
```

Restart the `sssd` service and test.