# (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Permission denied)

Tags: cron, root, sshd, pam

When tailing /var/log/cron i noticed that the cron job is failing due to PAM permissions.  In my access.conf  i do have the following uncommented to make sure (or what i thought was making sure) that root did have permissions to run cron jobs.

```
# User "root" should be allowed to get access via cron .. tty5 tty6.
+ : root : cron crond :0 tty1 tty2 tty3 tty4 tty5 tty6
```

I'm on Centos 7 Kernel 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64, we have connected it to our Windows active directory instanc via  realm, sssd, kerberos. 
My installations steps can be found here [Best Auth Mech to Connect to Windows AD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427037/best-auth-mech-to-connect-to-windows-ad/427759#427759)

Im at a loss at the moment and cant figure out what may be causing this. I double checked that roots password didn't expire and it had not.  Current root access is configured though windows security groups.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
I added debug to end of my pam_access.so and got the following

`crond[17411]: pam_access(crond:account): login_access: user=root, from=cron, file=/etc/security/access.conf
crond[17411]: pam_access(crond:account): line 60: - : ALL EXCEPT wheel shutdown sync : LOCAL root
crond[17411]: pam_access(crond:account): list_match: list=ALL EXCEPT wheel shutdown sync, item=root
crond[17411]: pam_access(crond:account): user_match: tok=ALL, item=root
crond[17411]: pam_access(crond:account): string_match: tok=ALL, item=root
crond[17411]: pam_access(crond:account): user_match: tok=wheel, item=root
crond[17411]: pam_access(crond:account): string_match: tok=wheel, item=root
crond[17411]: pam_access(crond:account): user_match: tok=shutdown, item=root
crond[17411]: pam_access(crond:account): string_match: tok=shutdown, item=root
crond[17411]: pam_access(crond:account): user_match: tok=sync, item=root
crond[17411]: pam_access(crond:account): string_match: tok=sync, item=root
crond[17411]: pam_access(crond:account): user_match=1, "root"
crond[17411]: pam_access(crond:account): list_match: list=LOCAL root, item=root
crond[17411]: pam_access(crond:account): from_match: tok=LOCAL, item=cron
crond[17411]: pam_access(crond:account): string_match: tok=LOCAL, item=cron
crond[17411]: pam_access(crond:account): from_match=1, "cron"
crond[17411]: pam_access(crond:account): access denied for user`root' from `cron'

Comment: For me to run as root, i login with my domain account, use `sudo -i` to switch to root, enter my password and im root.  When i run `tty` i get `/dev/pst/#` - I tried adding `ttyp*` and `pts` and `pts*` into the access.conf but no luck.

Comment: As your debug logs show that `- : ALL EXCEPT wheel shutdown sync : LOCAL root` is before `+ : root : cron crond :0 tty1 tty2 tty3 tty4 tty5 tty6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up rearranging my access.conf to the below.  In a sense i put the cron entry as my second entry in the config file which seems to correctly set the permissions for root to accessing cron.

```
 #
 # Disallow non-root logins on tty1
 #
 #-:ALL EXCEPT root:tty1
 #
 # User "root" should be allowed to get access via cron .. tty5 tty6.
 + : root : cron crond :0 tty1 tty2 tty3 tty4 tty5 tty6
 #
 # Disallow console logins to all but a few accounts.
 #
 -:ALL EXCEPT wheel shutdown sync:LOCAL root
```

If someone knows but i suspect that permissions are built on how they are entered in the config.  Even if you have permission via a entry in the config, if a line before that entry denies you access, it then overwrites the grant entry since it came first?

Answer (score 0):

As the next line reads:

`crond[17411]: pam_access(crond:account): access denied for user root' from cron'`

Looks like it's been cron who has denied access. Check if you have a `cron.allow` or `cron.deny` file in your system, usually in your 
`/etc` or `/etc/cron.d` directory. If you have a `cron.allow` file you will need to add your user there, it you have a `cron.deny` file and root is listed there you will need to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i don't have a cron.allow only a cron.deny but the were no entries so nothing was being denied.  I found the arrangement of of my access.conf file was causing the permission denied.